# area under the curve is equal to the volume of solid revolved around the x-axis

Tags: calculus

Any help with this past exam question is greatly appreciated ...

Give two functions which have the property that the area under the curve is equal to the volume of solid revolved around the x-axis across all values.

My attempt ...

Area under the curve = volume of solid revolved around the x-axis

$$\int_{a}^{b}\ f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b}\pi f(x)^2 dx$$

$$ f(x) = \pi f(x)^2 $$

$$ \pi f(x) = 1 $$

$$ f(x) = 1/\pi $$

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ also works.